# Does the Flutter ScopedModel only work with top-level variables?

Tags: dart, flutter

Does the ScopedModel only work with top-level variables or can I have a reload on change for a variable in a custom class that’s part of the Model?
For example,

```
class ExampleModel extends Model {

  MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  void modifyingFunction(){
    myClass.variable = 5;
  }
}
```

If I were to run `modifyingFunction`, could I then notify listeners automatically? I'm trying to coordinate 2 items in a list view to interact with each other in a way that only one item will be able to be selected at a time, and if it is selected, to deselect the other one.[image: Example Image]

Comment: You are missing a call to `notifyListeners()`?

Comment: This code was an example of the class, I didn't include the notifyListeners in the example. I just want to know which variables are listened to

Comment: oh, I misunderstood you - there is no magic in scoped model, variables aren't listened to.  notifyListeners just tells the subscribed widgets to rebuild.

Comment: Ok, so then it needs to be a top-level function inside the `Model` so I can call notifyListeners()? And does it rebuild all Descendants or only the ones that use the variable that's changed?

Comment: Also, the listener would be the `ScopedModelDescendent`s that have the `rebuildOnChange` value set to `true`?

Comment: This isn't really a stackoverflow question - you should ask for more detailed API documentation or just look at the code.  It doesn't need to be a top level function, you just need to have access to the model instance.  No, there is nothing special about using a variable (because there is no watching).  any descendents with rebuildOnChange will rebuild

Comment: I think I have it now, thank you

Comment: @JonahWilliams and all descendants of the model  are subscribed, right?